# Compile errors with recent XCode Update

Tags: ios, sqlite, compiler-errors, cocoapods, grdb

I recently update XCode to 13.2.1 but my project now has compilation errors in place where never exist before. This is related to the library GRDB.swift for local DB.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: There's not enough code here to debug this, but this issue comes up commonly if you search for that error message. The solution is to break the expression up into smaller parts, as the error/warning suggests.

Comment: Yes, I already read the suggestion but this a function from the Library so, I can't modify it into smaller parts.

Comment: Then it seems like the options are likely 1) revert to an older version of Xcode 2) For the library and modify the code in the new version so that it is compilable 3) Submit and issue to the repo and hope they will fix it

Comment: *Above should read "fork" not "for"

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by splitting the DB filters into multiple read db queue and appending all the results to a big one array of results. Maybe this is not the best practice for it but works for now and I will optimize in the future. Thanks everyone for help.

Especial thanks to @jnpdx for the idea

[image]

[image]